# Expression must have struct or union type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make a stack / linkedlist implementation in C with. I'm struggling on the `pop` function of a stack.

Here's what my stack/linkedlist implementation looks like :

```
// a cell
struct cell_s
{
  void *elem;
  struct cell_s *next;
};
typedef struct cell_s cell_t;

// the list is a pointer to the first cell
struct linkedlist_s
{
  struct cell_s *head;
  int len;
};
typedef struct linkedlist_s linkedlist_t;
```

Here's the pop function :

```
/**
 * Pop remove and return the head
 */
cell_t *pop(linkedlist_t *list)
{
    if ((*list).len == 0) {
        // we cannot pop an empty list
        return NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell_t* tmp = (*list).head;
        (*list).head = (*list).head.next; // <-- error occurs here
        (*tmp).next = NULL;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I did wrong. `(*list).head` is a `struct cell_s` so I should be able to access the attribute `next` ? But compiler won't let me do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Solved by replacing `(*list).head = (*list).head.next` with `(*list).head = (*tmp).next`

Comment: Besides the build error (which is simple, what is the type of `(*list).head` (or `list->head`)?) you also have some possible undefined behaviors while dereferencing potential uninitialized or null pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `head` field is not a `struct cell_s`.  It is a `struct cell_s *`, i.e. a pointer to `struct cell_s`.  As such, you need to use the `->` operator to dereference and access the member.

```
list->head = list->head->next;
```

Note also that `ptr->field` is easier to read than `(*ptr).field`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know `->` was a thing in C

Comment: @truvaking Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.